# ajax call only showing input values for the first item in for each loop. Need it to display depending on context of button click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying trying to post data to a controller based on the context of the button click in the for each loop. The response is only showing the first iteration of the loop.

```
@foreach($obj['questions'] as $question)
        <form class="col-md-12" id="upvote">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{$question->id}}" id="question_id" data-id="{{$question->id}}" class="form-control question_id">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{$user->id}}" id="user_id" data-id="{{$user->id}}" class="form-control user_id">
        <button class="btn btn-xs fas fa-arrow-up btn-submit" style="{{ in_array($question->id, $upvotes) ? 'color:gray' : 'color:orange' }}" {{ in_array($question->id, $upvotes) ? 'disabled' : null }}></button>
        </form>
@endforeach
```

And my ajax script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $('.btn-submit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var question_id = $("input[id=question_id]").val();
        var user_id = $("input[id=user_id]").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('welcome.upvoteAjax') }}",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {question_id:question_id, user_id:user_id},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

My route:

```
Route::post('/upvoteAjax', 'WelcomeController@upvoteAjax')->name('welcome.upvoteAjax');
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
public function upvoteAjax(Request $request){
   if($request->ajax()) {
      return response()->json($request);
   }
}
```

The response I get in console is (I attached a screenshot of the browser as well):

```
(index):593 {question_id: "736", user_id: "1"}
(index):593 {question_id: "736", user_id: "1"}
(index):593 {question_id: "736", user_id: "1"}
```

This is the output regardless of which item in the loop I click. The output that I want is the question and the user associated with the iteration of the loop that is displayed on the front end. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks.

[image: This is a screenshot of the console in chrome]

Answer (score 1):

After referencing [Aditya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56084889/3748494) and understanding how the references work I did some more searching and now this works for me

```
$('.btn-upvote').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); 
   var question_id = $(this).parent().find('.question_id').val();
   var user_id = $(this).parent().find('.user_id').val();
       $.ajax({
           url: "{{ route('welcome.upvoteAjax') }}",
           type: 'POST',
           data: {question_id:question_id, user_id:user_id},
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function (data) {
               console.log(data);
           }
       });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are clicking the submit button, You're fetching the value from the first field it finds example

`<input id="question_id">`.

A better way to solve this issue would calling the closeset elements input types to get the value:

```
    var question_id = $(this).closest('.question_id').val();
```

This will make sure the form values corresponds the input that button is submitting. Also ID is unique for each element.

here try this:

```
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
btns.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        let question_id =  btn.parentNode.children[0].value
        let user_id = btn.parentNode.children[1].value

        $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('welcome.upvoteAjax') }}",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {question_id: question_id, user_id: user_id},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
        })

    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Trying to wrap my head around this since ajax is new to me but after I did this, I am getting an empty array. Is there something else I have to do besides this? I am assuming $this is referencing the context of each item in the loop but its just not outputting anything in practice.

Comment: this is refrencing the button that was clicked, and closest is used to find the value of input closes to the button as they'll be in the same form.

Comment: @NickK i just posted a code that'll help you to fetch the correct values each time the button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks @Aditya, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56085791/3748494) worked for me. Let me know if you have any additional feedback. Thanks